# I am trying to build ADT map using List. I got everything working but erase(key) function

Tags: list, dictionary, iterator, adt

I am trying to build ADT map using List and iterator. I got everything working but erase(key) function. I am writing erase(int key) function where I try to delete particular (key, value) from the list with erase(key) function. Following is my ease(key) function. What is the best way to approach this?

```
void Hash::erase(int key) {
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    list<Pair>::iterator itr;

    bucketArrays[index].erase(bucketArrays[index].begin(), bucketArrays[index].end());

    return;
}
```

---

Map.h

```
 #ifndef MAP_H_
   #define MAP_H_

#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

struct Pair {
    int key;
    int value;

    Pair(int k, int v) : key(k), value(v){}
};

class Hash {
private:
    int buckets;
    list<Pair>* bucketArrays;
public:
    Hash();
    int hashFunction(int);
    void put(int, int);
    void find(int);
    void erase(int);
    void print();
};

Hash::Hash() {
    buckets = 19;
    bucketArrays = new list<Pair>[buckets];
}

int Hash::hashFunction(int k) {
    return (abs((3 * k) + 2) % 19);
}

void Hash::put(int key, int value) {
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    bucketArrays[index].push_back(Pair(key, value));
    return;
}

void Hash::find(int key) {
    int count = 0;
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    list<Pair>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = bucketArrays[index].begin(); itr != bucketArrays[index].end(); itr++) {
        if (itr->key == key) {
            cout << itr->value << endl;
        }
    }
}

void Hash::eraseValue(int key) {
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    list<Pair>::iterator itr;

    bucketArrays[index].erase(bucketArrays[index].begin(), bucketArrays[index].end());

    return;
}

void Hash::print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        cout << "\n" << i << " |";
        list<Pair>::iterator itr;
        for (itr = bucketArrays[i].begin(); itr != bucketArrays[i].end(); itr++) {
            int key = itr->key;
            int value = itr->value;
            if (itr == itr) {
                cout << "->";
            }
            cout << "(" << key << "," << value << ")";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n--------" << endl;
}

#endif // !MAP_H_
```

---

```
#include "Map.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Hash H;
    H.put(24, 17);
    H.put(32, 19);
    H.put(52, 31);
    H.put(62, 18);
    H.put(41, 12);
    H.put(12, 9);
    H.put(17, 2);
    H.put(18, 10);
    H.put(2, 91);
    H.put(13, 8);
    H.put(60, 18);
    H.put(31, 19);
    H.print();
    
    cout << "find(52): ";
    H.find(52);
    cout << "find(32): ";
    H.find(32);
    cout << "find(13): ";
    H.find(13);
    
    cout << "find(41): ";
    H.find(41);

    cout << "find(60): ";
    H.find(60);

    cout << "find(17): ";
    H.find(17);

    cout << "find(13): ";
    H.find(13);
    cout << "--------" << endl;
    H.erase(2);
    H.erase(60);
    H.print();
    /*
    H.find(46);
    H.erase(1);
    H.find(52);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Console Display

0 |->(12,9)->(31,19)
1 |
2 |
3 |->(32,19)->(13,8)
4 |
5 |
6 |->(52,31)
7 |
8 |->(2,91)
9 |
10 |
11 |->(41,12)->(60,18)
12 |
13 |
14 |
15 |->(17,2)
16 |
17 |->(24,17)->(62,18)
18 |->(18,10)
--------
find(52): 31
find(32): 19
find(13): 8
find(41): 12
find(60): 18
find(17): 2
find(13): 8
--------

0 |->(12,9)->(31,19)
1 |
2 |
3 |->(32,19)->(13,8)
4 |
5 |
6 |->(52,31)
7 |
8 |
9 |
10 |
11 |
12 |
13 |
14 |
15 |->(17,2)
16 |
17 |->(24,17)->(62,18)
18 |->(18,10)
--------
```

What else can I do with iterator ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-implement find in erase. You *push* to put; you *pop* to erase. You find/peek to find. Are there no popping functions? You used push_back in put.

```
    bucketArrays[index].erase(bucketArrays[index].begin(), bucketArrays[index].end());
```

isn't erasing anything, just iterating the array "bucketArrays[index].erase" from the indexes specified.